# webkit browsers incorrectly scaling items when page is zoomed

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, zooming, scaling

Safari and Chrome do not correctly scale items in an HTML page when the zoom level is different from 100%.

The width of items is changed from 1 to 2 px in comparison to the 100% zoom level.

How can I correct this?

Comment: You need to work on the grammer of your question if you want to get helpful answers. You Won't get as much help if it is hard work to read your sentences.